# Hibernate aggregates + Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Hibernate with my Spring MVC project.

Lets say my model has 2 objects each linked to Oracle tables, respectively `USERS (USERID, NAME)` and `USERMONEYDATA (CATEGORY, USERID, AMOUNT)`

My users can add , edit and remove rows in `USERMONEYDATA`, that belongs to them of course.
Now, I want to have a view that aggregates those data.

Using oracle, I made a simple view  to get the total amount per user and category :

```
select  userid, category, sum(amount)
from USERS a inner join USERMONEYDATA b on a.USERID = b.USERID
group by userid, category
```

But what is the best way to use it? should I create a new MODEL object specifically for this view ?

Should I aggregate directly in Hibernate ? But if yes, how do I display the results if I dont have a specific POJO object to map it to ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `User` and `UserMoneyData` are mapped as Hibernate entities, it's a natural choice to run aggregate queries in Hibernate.

By default, HQL or JPQL `SELECT` clause with multiple paths produces tuples in the form of `Object[]`. Since this kind of data is read-only, you may display these arrays directly, without converting them to objects.

Another option is to create a POJO for representing results of the query and use a constructor syntax `SELECT NEW MoneyReport(u.userId, d.category, SUM(d.amount)) ...`. These POJOs don't need to be entities.

**See also:**

- [Chapter 15. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)